# Performing numerical operations on array values column in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

Perform numerical operations on a hive table

| id | array | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | [10:20] | 2 |
| b | [30:40:50] | 5 |

I want to convert above table into the following

| id | array | value | converted_array |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | [10:20] | 2 | [20:40] |
| b | [30:40:50] | 5 | [150:200:250] |

**I want to multiply 'array' column with 'value' column, and create a new column 'converted_array' using hql. I know how to do this in python but I was wondering if there's a way to do it in hive.**

Answer (score 0):

Try using collect_set over exploded view as shown below, this will multiply the constant integer value in the value column with each element in the array(using explode) and then return the result(using collect_set):

```
select id, collect_set(pve) as pv, value1, collect_set(pve*value1) as converted_array
from stacko1
lateral view explode(price_lov) t as pve
group by id,value1;
```

This should give you the desired output.
[image]

Comment: I am facing the following error with explode function org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: UDFArgumentException explode() takes an array or a map as a parameter

Comment: In your question you have mentioned the column is an array, but the error says its not an array, can you check the datatype of the column you are using in explode and the type of data within the column and publish it here for reference?